# special characters in password in curl command

Tags: jenkins, curl, passwords, character

In my password, there are two special characters are there `>` and `:`, when i run curl command it's not working with error:
`The system cannot find the file`, even i tried escape characters in my password as `\>` and `\:`.
Also i did double quotes e.g. `curl -u "abc\\sys_account:Tabc>fg:Eh" abc.org`
Still I haven't get any luck.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Also it's not working with WithCredentials Pipeline syntax in Jenkins.

Comment: Can you replace `>` with `&gt;` and `:` with `&colon;`? Also, use the following format: `curl -d -u 'abc\\sys_account:Tabc&gt;fg&colon;Eh' abc.org`. I have replaced double quote with single quote.

Comment: it's not working. `gt is not recognized as internal or external command`

Comment: Can you paste the command you used?

Comment: Can you use  `--data-urlencode` before password?